# Save passwords for applications not working

Tags: security, thunderbird, keyring

I installed a elementary OS on my notebook last week.
Everything works fine until the password saving for applications like Thunderbird or ownCloud desktop client. I never got this problem before. I installed seahorse today to manage my keyrings. After I created a new keyring and set it as default, Thunderbird and ownCloud are asking for my passwords every time. Do you know what to do? With Ubuntu I never got these problems.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Timo.